# Horizontally justified list collapsing on first load (Chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome

When re-building my Web site, I adjusted the menu to be justified horizontally automatically:
[image]

It worked in all browsers, but now doesn't work in Chrome when you first load the page. The menu's items are collapsed:
[image]

Oddly enough, when you reload the page, the menu becomes justified once again.

I'm not sure whether this is a bug in the browser or not. I've tried isolating the CSS and clearing my browser's cache to find the problem, but had no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for fixing this issue?

Live site: http://www.restoration-art.com/?debug=1
(Also, I've deployed a hotfix that styles the menu in another way, so to view the old styling, append `?debug=1` to the URL.)

Comment: Hey bud. I tried it in an up to date chrome several times and couldn't replicate the issue. My gut is it that it isn't an issue at all.

Comment: @agconti Thanks for your help, but it's still behaving like that with me. Did you try typing in the URL in a new tab after clearing your cache? That's how I reproduced the problem.

Comment: @cizmc I got the same issue once I cleared my cache. Its wierd that it works perfectly on refresh. Why dont you include both css files in one style sheet. It seems like the css loads after the page renders.

Comment: @agconti I think this is a bug with the browser. The menu CSS is in the same file as the other CSS. The second CSS file is for mobile devices only. Also, when you look in Web Inspector, the style rules are loaded.

Comment: @agconti Also, I've deployed a hotfix that styles the menu in another way, so to view the old styling, append `?debug=1` to the URL.

Comment: I tried testing it for you in the latest version of Chrome on both Mac & PC - it loaded justified on both. I also tried emptying my cache and visiting the site again in a new tab - still ok.

Comment: @cizmic I tried the `debug=1` version in incognito mode, and still found the same issue. Its very strange that the style rules are there, perhaps though its still a parsing issue. Maybe try to move the spacing to the very top of the css sheet to make sure?

Comment: @David try looking at the site in incognito mode, thats the only way I could replicate it.

Comment: @agconti - I tried that as well - still ok for me!